# How to prevent tests being bundled by rollup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, rollupjs

I am building a react component package and want to exclude my tests folder from being bundled in my dist file that is built from rollup.

My file structure looks like this after running `rollup -c`

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── tests
│      ├── index.test.js
├── src
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── tests
│      ├── index.test.tsx
```

My rollup config looks like this:

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'

import pkg from './package.json'

export default {
  input: 'src/index.tsx',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      exports: 'named',
      sourcemap: true,
      strict: false
    }
  ],
  plugins: [typescript()],
  external: ['react', 'react-dom', 'prop-types']
}
```

How can I exclude my tests directory from being bundled into the `dist` file when runnning rollup?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you care about type checking your test files, instead of excluding them in `tsconfig.json`, do that exclusion as a param to the rollup typescript plugin in `rollup.config.js`.

```
plugins: [
  /* for @rollup/plugin-typescript */
  typescript({
    exclude: ["**/__tests__", "**/*.test.ts"]
  })

  /* or for rollup-plugin-typescript2 */
  typescript({
    tsconfigOverride: {
      exclude: ["**/__tests__", "**/*.test.ts"]
    }

  })
]
```

Comment: You need to nest the `exclude` property under the `tsconfigOverride` key. Refer [docs](https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2/blob/master/README.md#plugin-options)

Comment: Thanks @AnshSaini, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 12):

You can exclude tests in **tsconfig.json** e.g.

```
"exclude": [
    "**/tests",
    "**/*.test.js",
  ]
```